# How Can I pass params with an API client to vue-head?

Tags: vue.js

I am passing params from my API to [vue-head](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head) but every time I do that it send me undefined in the head this is the code:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    programs: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    getProgram() {
      this.api.http.get(`videos/program/${this.programSlug}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.programs = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error
        });
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: function() {
      return {
        inner: this.programs.name,
        separator: '|',
        complement: 'Canal 10'
      };
    }
  }
}
```

any idea what I am doing wrong with my code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify you are fetching the information correctly. Use console log and go to network tab and verify you are fetching the data correct, you might have to comment out vue-head. But what I think is that the problem might be due to vue-head rendering before the api call finishes then no data is being passed.

If you are using vue-router this can be easily solved with beforeRouteEnter() hook. But if not! apparently vue-head has an event that you can emit to update the component after render.
I haven't tried this but it should work. you can add the function below to your methods and call it after the promise is resolved i.e in the then closure.

```
methods: {
  getProgram() {
    this.api.http.get(`videos/program/${this.programSlug}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.programs = response.data
        this.$emit('updateHead')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errors = error
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I call it in this way : **this.api.http.get(`videos/program/${this.programSlug}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.programs = response.data
        }).bind(afterFetchingData); ** and how should I pass to the head "inner"??

Comment: you will not call that in the head. This is an event emitter and the vue-head component is built and set to listen to this in order to update. I updated my code to where it should go.